# multilevel/nested headers in CSV files

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

How can I "make" multilevel/nested headers in CSV files please?

Example:

```
-----------------------------------------
|        Big 1      |        Big 2      |
-----------------------------------------
| Small A | Small B | Small C | Small D |
-----------------------------------------
|                  ...                  |
```

Comment: What's your data source? And how will you interact with the CSV?